# Looking for <table> in html file

Tags: html, c++, file

so I need to find the phrase `"<table"` (without the ">") which is at the beginning of a line in a html file. This is part of my code:

```
char table[7];
string scrap;
while(ifs.tellg()!=-1)
{

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        ifs.get(c);
        table[i]=c;
    }

    if(!strcmp("<table",table))
    {
        cout<<"Table found";

    }
    else
    {
        getline(ifs,scrap);

    }
```

If the `<table` is at the begging of the file it works, but when it's in line 100 or so it doesn't. I think it might be something about that it takes the new line character and puts it in the table array so for example instead of table being `"<table" its "\n<tabl"`.

What can I do so this works?

Comment: `table` probably isn't going to be null-terminated, so you have undefined behaviour when calling `strcmp`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, not neccessarily. The code as posted doesn't have any undefined behavior in it.

Comment: Are you sure that the line you are looking for starts with `<table`?  And you need to make sure that `table[6]` = 0 (as @JonathanPotter pointed out).

Comment: @ScottHunter, no he does not. Not in the given code.

Comment: @SergeyA: I was not aware that C++ guaranteed that array elements are initialized to 0; thanks for the info.

Comment: @SergeyA If `table[6] != 0` then the comparison will never succeed. `strcmp` won't consider the strings to match if they're not the same length.

Comment: @ScottHunter Local arrays are not initialized by default.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, both your comments are true, but neither of those facts triggers undefined behavior. In fact, behaviour is very well defined.

Comment: @SergeyA Semantics, the code may not (or may) behave how the user expects / intends which is the point - would you prefer "unpredictable behavior" instead? And is it sensible for you to imply that null termination isn't important?

Comment: Why don't you read the whole file into a string first and then do *one* search? HTML files are usually not several gigabytes, so memory should not be a problem. Second remark: Are you sure that the characters in your file fit into 8 bit?

Comment: @JonathanPotter, terminlogy is extremely important. 'Undefined behaviour' is a very specific term. The code shown does not exhibit nor undefined, nor unpredictable behavior. It is defined, and I can easily predict how it will behave. The code most likely will not behave the way OP would want it to behave, but you can't call every bug in the code 'an undefined behavior'

Comment: @SergeyA: "I can easily predict" and "most likely will not behave" don't both usually apply to the same thing.

Comment: @ScottHunter, could not agree more. You seem to misunderstand my statement. 'Most likely' refers to my guess to the OP's intent (a very educated guess, I must admit). There is no probability in regards to program behaviour.

Comment: @SergeyA: In order to predict how the call to `strcmp` behaves, one would need to know the content of `table[6]`; I, for one, do not see a way to do that.  Maybe you would enlighten us if you do.

Comment: @ScottHunter, ok, you got me. While most of the time (say, 99.999%) the table will not be nul-terminated, and strcmp will return strings to be not equal, there is an off-chance that it will be and in this case strcmp will return 0 if the sequence read was 'table'. However, it is still NOT undefined behavior in any way.

Comment: @SergeyA I'm happy to withdraw the word "undefined" and substitute with "unpredictable", if it will make you happy. I'm not sure how this argument over semantics helps the OP, who has probably missed the important point that `strcmp` needs its inputs to be null-terminated. Still I'm not sure that helping the OP was ever your goal.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, my goal was to make sure people are using proper terms and outline the issues correctly. You do not.

Comment: @SergeyA Given that your first reply to ScottHunter **specifically contradicted** his statement that the string needs to be null-terminated, your goal is certainly questionable. However this argument has gone on long enough. Chalk it up as a win if it makes you feel important.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `find` method in `std::string`. You can find it's documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/).

For example you can do something like this (assuming `ifs` is an `istream`).

```
while (ifs.tellg() != -1) {
    getline(ifs, &scrap);
    size_t pos = scrap.find("<table", 0);
    if (pos != string::npos) {
        // You have found your target! Do whatever you want.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current algotithm is searching in blocks of 6 bytes:

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    ifs.get(c);
    table[i]=c;
}
```

So, if `<table` starts at pos 2 (after 2 spaces or tabs for example), you will jump over it.

Also, several html files don't even use newlines, so there could be all sorts of data before `<table`. Or even when using newlines, `<table` is not guaranteed to be the first tag in the line.

Even if you are searching for `<table` at the very beginning of the line, consider what happens if there is an empty line: `getline(ifs,scrap);` will get you to the next line, if that line (and maybe the following one) is empty, `get(c)` will return a newline character (or 2 if `\r\n`).

I think you should use a string search in each line, but if the file is large and no newlines are used, it might be better to scan the full file, instead of scanning the lines. But then, instead of comparing each 6-byte block, you would scan for `<` first, if found, compare the following byte, etc.. (or use an algorithm like [Boyer–Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)).

You may also need to take care (skip) of `<table`'s inside comments for example.